# Speech Recognition

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to recognize simple words like apple, orange , yes, no, stop etc  and publish them using a rostopic. I tried using pocketsphinx package with a dictionary, but the results were not very encouraging since the software confused different words. Is there a better solution using ros?

-P

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224065/speech-recognition/) by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2016-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Like [this](http://wiki.ros.org/gspeech) project for example?

Regarding Pocketsphinx: Have you tried another language model/training your language?
Also make sure your microphone quality is fine.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0